# ctypes python std::string

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

I am working with ctypes using C++ as the backend. Now there is a function like this in C++:

```
void HandleString(std::string something){

   ...
}
```

I am wondering how to call this function from python - there is no ctype (c_char_p wont work obviously) to send a string parameter to this function...

How can I fix this and pass a string from Python to c++ (and changing the parameter to char* something is not and option)

PS Could I create a workaround like this?

1. send the python string as c_char_p to C++ function that converts char* to std::string
2. return the string or its pointer somehow???!! (how?) to python
3. send it from python to HandleString function (but again I feel like I would have to change the parameter to string* here)

Comment: If you're going to workaround, wouldn't it make more sense to send your c_char_p to a C++ function that converts it to `std::string` and then calls `HandleString` immediately? In fact, there's an implicit conversion from `const char*` to `std::string`, so your workaround function can just use the pointer as the argument expression for `HandleString`. Don't bother trying to pass the `std::string` back to Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the simplest approach is to write a thin c++ wrapper around the library for the sole purpose of renegotiating the parameters from python into the more complex c++ classes.

Such an approach would also help remedy future problems of the same kind, without adding any real complexity to neither the python code or the c++ code.

Answer (score 4):

The Python C API converts Python `str` objects into `char*`, and there
is an implicit conversion in C++ from `char*` (actually `char const*`)
to `std::string`.

If the Python strings can contain null characters, you'll have to use
`PyString_AsStringAndSize` to convert, and pass around the two values
(the `char*` and the `Py_ssize_t`); there's an explicit conversion of
these to `std::string` as well: `std::string( pointer, length )`.

Answer (score 1):

Memory layout of std::string depends on the library, platform and architecture. The code below works for a 64bit DLL build with Visual C++ on Windows. If not working you need to adapt the StdString structure. Good luck!

```
def createStdStringObj(s):
    # Structure that represents the memory layout of std::string
    # that depends on library, platform and architecture used.
    # The layout works for a 64 bit DLL build with Visual C++
    # on Windows, adapt it if it is not working!
    class StdString(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("data", c_char_p),         # Pointer to character data
            ("size", c_size_t),         # Size of the string
            ("capacity", c_size_t),     # Capacity of the string
        ]
    data = s.encode("utf-8")
    stds = StdString()
    stds.data = c_char_p(data)
    stds.size = len(data)
    stds.capacity = len(data)
    return stds

dllFcn(createStdStringObj('this is it'))
```

Comment: This approach will work only by chance e.g. small string optimization will break it. So even it may work on concrete system/compiler/std library combination, it is not really portable. Also, C++ `HandleString` will try to deallocate memory owned by `data` on its exit, given it takes `std::string` by value.

Comment: The code works for a 64bit DLL build with Visual C++ on Windows. There is no small string optimization over DLL boundaries. Argument `std::string something` of `HandleString` does a copy of the string if it is changed and will never deallocate memory from extern.

Comment: Yep, you are right, I need to take back words about argument destruction, should have checked it before posting. About platform it works on: your answer should incorporate it then. About SSO: turns out it does not matter, since example I was about to show (libc++'s `std::string`) has totally different memory layout [https://joellaity.com/2020/01/31/string.html]

Comment: What I meant with my comments: if someone uses your code on non-Windows machine, will will not get expected result. So let's write at least a warning about it